# Checking contents of 2 strings

Tags: java, string

I am new to java programming and I was wondering how I can know if a certain string like "Hello" contains "Hlo" (in this order). I used the .contains method but it only works if the letters are consecutive. So how can I handle cases like the above?

P.S: For example, if we ask if "oll" is in "Hello" false is returned as "Hello" doesn't contain "oll", and if we ask if "elo" is in "Hello", true is returned.
Thank you.

Comment: This is what regular expressions were created to do: Pattern matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just, be simple!**

```
public static boolean containsCharsInOrder(String str, String pattern) {
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() && j < pattern.length(); i++)
        if (str.charAt(i) == pattern.charAt(j))
            j++;

    return j == pattern.length();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex, you could build a regex from the word to test, by putting, between character a possible amount of chars, which will be filled with the missing ones

For example `Hlo -> .*H.*l.*l.*o.*`

```
public static boolean checkStrings(String a, String b) {
    String pattern = "^.*" + String.join(".*", b.split("")) + ".*$";
    return a.matches(pattern);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(checkStrings("Hello", "Hllo")); // true
    System.out.println(checkStrings("Hello", "oll"));  // false
}
```

---

This can be inlined

```
public static boolean checkStrings(String a, String b) {
    return a.matches(".*" + String.join(".*", b.split("")) + ".*");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's call subsequence. You can iterate over main string and if match found increase the index of search string and at last if all character of search string match in main string then it's a subsequence.

```
  boolean isSubSequence(String searchString, String mainString) {
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mainString.length() && j < searchString.length(); i++)
      if (searchString.charAt(j) == mainString.charAt(i))
        j++;
    return (j == searchString.length());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over each character of the String and if the first correct letter is found, then check if the other characters are following.

A possible implementation of this would be following:

```
public static boolean containsString(String base, String search) {
    for(int i = 0; i <= (base.length() - search.length()); i ++) {
        if(base.charAt(i) == search.charAt(0)) {
            boolean containsString = true;
            for(int j = 1; j < search.length(); j ++) {
                if(search.charAt(j) != base.charAt(i+j)) {
                    containsString = false;
                }
            }
            if(containsString)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd break the "search" string into characters, and for each such character check its [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-int-) in the string, starting from the previously found index:

```java
public static boolean containsCharsInOrder(String str, String chars) {
    int len = chars.length();
    int startIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        ch = chars.charAt(i);
        int ind = str.indexOf(ch, startIndex);
        if (ind == -1) {
            return false;
        }
        startIndex = ind;
    }
    return true;
}
```